Getting specific child element with Selenium
I´m currentlly working with Selenium on python and i´m facing a problem. Right now, I´m looking for products on Amazon in order to get they price. After I look for one, I have identified a specific class for each result, as seen below.

Right into that class, there is a  called 'a-price-whole' that contains the total whole price of the product. Right now, I have tried to access them like:
totalPrices = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sg-col-4-of-24 sg-col-4-of-12 s-result-item s-asin sg-col-4-of-16 sg-col s-widget-spacing-small sg-col-4-of-20" "//span[@class='a-price-whole']")
However, it gives me an error, saying that it can´t find the element. My question is, how could and should I access that  in order to get them?
I have tried to access them using XPath with seems I´m not doing it propertly.

What does, "it doesn´t work at all" mean? Are you getting an error? Are you getting empty string? If you are getting an error, edit your question and post the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

Scraping amazon is against their Terms of Service (TOS). Don't do that.

First, it´s just for educational purposes, so don´t get like that, please. Second of all, this screenshot has the class selected and this way it's easier to see the hierarchy. I understand your point but please, just don´t take time to check the problems and just try to help with the solutions as it´s really not that important for understanding the issue

We have rules here on SO. You, like all other users, are expected to follow those rules. Fix your question. If it's for educational purposes, use a different site. There are plenty of other sites that you can use for training.

I couldn't find class=a-price-whole in the HTML as you have stated. Having said that, you can use below XPath expression to locate each of the product price in the page:
//span[@class='a-color-base']

Refer the code below with in-line explanation:
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.es/s?k=3HB4131X2&__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2CQP9HLFX6PR7&sprefix=3hb4131x2%2Caps%2C118&ref=nb_sb_noss_1")

# below line will create explicit wait object with wait time of 10s
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

# Click on Accept cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "sp-cc-accept"))).click()

# below 2 lines will store all product names and their prices in a list variable
totalProductNames = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal']")))
totalPrices = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-color-base']")))

# below for loop will iterate through both the lists in parallel and print each of the product and price
for product, price in zip(totalProductNames,totalPrices):
    print(product.text, price.text)

time.sleep(10)

Console result:
Balay 3HB4131X2 - Horno, Multifunción, A, Encastrable, 60 cm, 71 l, 7 F, Aqualisis, Ap. Abatible, Acero inoxidable, Control Comfort, Reloj electrónico con programación de inicio y paro, 2022 319,99 €
Balay 3HB4131B2 - Horno, Multifunción, A, Encastrable, 60 cm, 71 l, 7 F, Aqualisis, Ap. Abatible, blanco, Control Comfort, Reloj electrónico con programación de inicio y paro, Lanzamiento 2022 348,88 €
Balay 3HB4131X2 - Horno, Multifunción, A, Encastrable, 60 cm, 71 l, 7 F, Aqualisis, Ap. Abatible & 3EB865FR - Placa de inducción de 60 cm de ancho 653,00 €
Balay 3HB4131X2 - Horno, Multifunción, A, Encastrable, 60 cm, 71 l, 7 F, Aqualisis, Ap. Abatible, Acero inoxidable, 2022 & 3EB864EN Placa de inducción de 60cm sin marco, 3 zonas de inducción 604,08 €
BOSCH - Horno Multifunción, 60 cm, Serie 4, Asistente de Limpieza con Agua, Negro, HBA512ES0 249,32 €
Balay 3HB4841X2 - Horno, Multifunción, A, Encastrable, 60 cm, 71 l, 7 F, Pirólisis y Aqualisis, Ap. Abatible, Acero inoxidable, Control Comfort, 10 recetas, Mandos Ocultables, Lanzamiento 2022 295,23 €
Balay 3HB5158N2 - Horno, Multifunción, A, Encastrable, 60 cm, 71 l, 7 F, Aqualisis, Ap. Abatible, Cristal Negro, Control Comfort, 10 recetas, Lanzamiento 2022 301,43 €
AEG BEE435111M Horno Eléctrico Multifunción, Integrable, Limpieza AquaClean, 9 Funciones, Cocción Multinivel, Display LCD Táctil, Ventilador XXL, 72 L de Capacidad, Inox, Clase A+ 252,75 €
Bosch - Horno Multifunción, 60 cm, Serie 6, Recetas Automáticas, Asistente de Limpieza con Agua, Negro, HBA5360S0 237,11 €
Horno BALAY 3HB5888A6 Gris Antracita Pirólisis HC 694,09 €
Horno Pirolítico Balay 3HB4821X2 71 L 526,61 €
Bosch HORNO HBA5740S0, Pirólisis, Mandos ocultables, 1 clipRaíl, Cristal negro/inox 316,49 €
Bosch HBG5780S0 Horno Pirolítico, Serie 6, 71 L, Hasta 275 °C 405,32 €
Balay 3HB2031X0 - Horno Eléctrico, 60x60 cm, Capacidad 66 L, Color Negro y Acero Inoxidable, 7 modos calentamiento / Aire 3D 304,67 €
UNIVERSALBLUE Horno Digital Cristal Negro | Clasificación Energética A | Guías Telescópicas + Bandeja + Rejilla 280,39 €
BALAY - Horno, 60 cm, 5 Funciones, Precalentamiento rápido, Negro, 3HB4000X2. 325,85 €
BALAY - Horno, 60 cm, 5 Funciones, Precalentamiento rápido, Negro, 3HB5000N2. 362,89 €
Horno Multifunci+¦n BALAY 3HB5000B2 71L Cristal blanco 363,60 €
Balay 3HB2030X0 - Horno (Medio, Horno eléctrico, 66 L, 66 L, 1 estanterías, Negro, Acero inoxidable) 254,44 €
Zanussi ZOHNB0X1 Horno 5 funciones, Grill Integrado, Mandos Fijos, Antihuellas, Inox, Clase A, 56 Litros [Clase de eficiencia energética A] 214,89 €

Process finished with exit code 0

